# Possible to create a script to open and close bat files

Tags: python, batch-file, cmd

So I have several .bat files that open up the cmd give it a title and start running a script. I was curious if it would be possible to create a script that would open these files let them run for say 12 hours, then close them. Then wait 12 hours and open them again. Rinse and repeat.

I'm not looking for someone to just come on and do it for me i'm just looking for an example or even what platform i could do this with.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [AT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755618(v=ws.10).aspx):

```
at 00:00 /every:M,T,W,Th,F,S,Su MyHappyFunScript.cmd
```

This gets you started. There are UNIX command utilities for Windows to get the PID of the script you run, to sleep for a number of seconds, and to kill a running task by PID. E.g.,

```
at 00:00 /every:M,T,W,Th,F,S,Su "run myscript && sleep 43200 && taskkill /IM myscript"
```